# Send a Message to JMS queue using java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jms, glassfish-4

I have successfully developed and JMS queue using Oracle Glass-fish server 4.1 version, Then I could send and read messages successfully using java EE application, but I need to implement Sender code to a Swing application, I used same code as Java EE application, but it is not working fine, please refer below code

```
public class SenderSwing {    
  /**
   * @param args the command line arguments
  */
public static void main(String[] args) {
   try {

       new SenderSwing().sendJMSMessageToDefaultQueue("Hi "+System.currentTimeMillis());

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
 private void sendJMSMessageToDefaultQueue(Object messageData) throws JMSException, NamingException {
    Context c = new InitialContext();
    ConnectionFactory cf = (ConnectionFactory) c.lookup("java:comp/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory");
    Connection conn = null;
    Session s = null;
    try {
        conn = cf.createConnection();
        s = conn.createSession(false, s.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Destination destination = (Destination) c.lookup("jms/defaultQueue");
        MessageProducer mp = s.createProducer(destination);            
        mp.send(createJMSMessageForjmsDefaultQueue(s, messageData));
    } finally {
        if (s != null) {
            try {
                s.close();
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.WARNING, "Cannot close session", e);
            }
        }
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.close();
        }
    }
}
 private Message createJMSMessageForjmsDefaultQueue(Session session, Object messageData) throws JMSException {
    // TODO create and populate message to send
    TextMessage tm = session.createTextMessage();
    tm.setText(messageData.toString());


    return tm;
}
```

}

above code giving me a exception like below,

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:662)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:350)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
at senderswing.SenderSwing.sendJMSMessageToDefaultQueue(SenderSwing.java:43)
at senderswing.SenderSwing.main(SenderSwing.java:35)
```

Can any one help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of server context, there's no default initial context factory class.

Try this in the beginning:

```
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, 
"com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
Context c = new InitialContext(env);
```

You will need glassfish-naming(or embedded-all) jar as a dependency.